# How to get the log message from "ServletContext.log("Hello World!")"?

Tags: tomcat, servlets, logging

I am using Tomcat v7, I want to get the log message with using ServletContext.log("Hello World!"), but I can not get any log from console or log file.
Does anyone please tell me how to config so that I can see the "Hello World!"?

(Seems it need config server.xml with adding Logger tag, I tried but see no log file generated.

)

**Appreciate your help.**

Answer (score -1):

[Tomcat Logging](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Logging) tells you about the logging.

Answer (score -1):

Look at the `tomcat/logs` dir - if you haven't configured something different, it should go there.